# How to add fragments inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created an activity, when I start an activity which implements viewpager, the viewpager created various fragments. I want to use different layouts for each fragment, but the problem is that the fragments is not show inside viewpager.

**DataActivity.java**

```
public class DataActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewPager myViewPager;
        MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_activity);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mytPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
}

     private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

         int numberOfPages = 5;
         public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)   {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int index) {

                return DataFirstFragment.newInstance();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return numberOfPages;
            }
}
}
```

**DataFirstFragment** is not shown inside viewpager

Anyone can help me please...!

Comment: Share some code you impemented for this.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for above problem, Only replce this

```
return DataFirstFragment.newInstance();
```

with:

```
return new DataFirstFragment();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Below code i don't see where do you add fragment to adaptor ? ?

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

         int numberOfPages = 5;
         public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)   {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int index) {

                return DataFirstFragment.newInstance();
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return numberOfPages;
            }
}
```

SO when `viewPager` asks `adaptor` to get item , it does not have anything.